# How to retrieve a list of physical printers using WMI?

Tags: wmi, printers, network-printers

I'm trying to get a list of hardware printers attached to a windows XP machine by using WMI. What i'd like is *not* the same as getting the list from Win32_Printers since i'd only like to get printers that physically exist as boxes, getting rid of all the "printer noise" like "Send to OneNote Driver", "Microsoft Shared Fax Driver", "Microsoft XPS Document Writer", etc...

By using WMICodeCreator tool i found out that i can't rely on the Local/Network properties being true (as of now, my network printer tells me that its network property is false...) so i'd like to know if there is another way to get the correct information?

*Bonus points* if i can get the usb printers attached to the computer: the Win32_USBHub property doesn't really help here since i can't get the correct description of "Printing Support" :)

Comment: maybe looking for Win32_Printer.MarkingTechnology or Win32_Printer.PortName?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no, this cannot be done directly - only some good guesses will help here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327763/is-there-a-possibility-to-differ-virtual-printer-from-physical-one

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post but I ran into the same requirements and figured I would post my end result for the next person to come along.

```
Dim oWMI, colPrinters, oItem, oPrinter
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colPrinters = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer where PrintProcessor <> 'winprint'")

For Each oPrinter in colPrinters
    If oPrinter.Attributes And 64 Then
        Wscript.Echo oPrinter.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This won't work if you are fetching this information remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I think that just physical printer use the `unidrv.dll`

```
string query = "select * from Win32_PrinterDriver";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj["Name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(obj["DriverPath"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: This is not correct.  Many physical printers use drivers other than `unidrv` and many virtual printers use `unidrv`.  You can't tell if a printer is physical or virtual based on the driver it's using.