# How to detect document and real hardware printers in .net?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, printing, wmi

As a requirement from customer we need to enumerate all printers connected to the system but "virtual" / document printers.

We tried to list printers via WMI (`SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer`)
or using `LocalPrintServer`.

It seems that there is no property which will says this printer is "virtual".

**Situation**

By default Windows comes with Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Fax, Microsoft Print to PDF.

My system has also two other printers, one local (Cannon MG300 series) and one network (UTAX 3206ci).

Also I installed Snagit, Universal Document Converter, OneNote and NovaPDF.

When I list my printers I've got

```
Universal Document Converter 
novaPDF 10 
Snagit 2019 
Send To OneNote 16 
OneNote 
Microsoft XPS Document Writer 
Microsoft Print to PDF 
Fax 
Canon MG3000 series 
3206ci
```

**Desired behaviour**

I'd like to achieve

```
Canon MG3000 series 
3206ci
```

Yes, of course, we can do some heuristics to somehow filter according to driver name, port value, but some of these printers still can slip trough.

Is there a way how to do it with 100% certainty?

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327763/is-there-a-possibility-to-differ-virtual-printer-from-physical-one